# Navigation drawer for android app

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have found a sample of Navigation drawer on
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
but the thing is when switching between drawers it shwitches images and i want switch between classes any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example isn't simply switching images. If you look closer you will see that it's creating a new `Fragment` for ever item selected. That is the component that you would most likely use when you say "switch between classes".

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```